# Outlook for iOS Randomly Increase Email Font by 10x

Tags: mac, ms-office

I have Outlook for iOS on a Mac. Whether I send or receive a message, or whether it is a new message or a reply, Outlook will increase the font of one sentence at random in the email. The increase is 10 times (if font size is 12, then it increases to 120; if 14, then 140 etc.) It looks like this:

[image]

It happens perhaps once in every 100 emails. There seems to be no pattern. And if I resend the same message, or ask a sender to resend to me the same message exactly, the font increase does not occur.

When looking at the source code of an affected message, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it looks like Outlook inserts a zero, "0", to the font size in a random line.

I search the web for an explanation to no avail. (Though I have seen a few other users that are describing a similar issue. Basically, Microsoft blames Apple and Apple blames Microsoft.)

Does anyone can make sense of this?

And is there a fix?

Comment: File a [bug report](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-report-a-bug-to-microsoft/adc9f7fb-60bf-4421-acf6-f28dbe55d74f).